# taking value at runtime and printing it's factorial in PlSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to find factorial of a number while taking it at runtime but I am getting an error

```
DECLARE
fact number :=1;
n number := &1;
BEGIN
while n > 0 loop
  fact:=n*fact;
  n:=n-1;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(fact);
END;
```

Comment: What's your DBMS? MySQL or Oracle? it seems like oracle.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `/` on a new line at the end and run it without the substitution variable and your code works:

```sql
DECLARE
fact number :=1;
n number := 3;
BEGIN
while n > 0 loop
  fact:=n*fact;
  n:=n-1;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(fact);
END;
/
```

and outputs:

> ```
> 6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e767b3a6c815a906c82a8f1e27c0fa4b)*

Since you have not said in the question what the error is, then it is probable that the error will either be related to:

- the missing `/` and Oracle trying to parse it as SQL statements rather than as a PL/SQL block; or
- something you are typing in when you provide the substitution variable (but since you, again, have not mentioned what you are substituting we cannot really comment on this).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use mathematical to achieve factorial.

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LN(Level))) factorial
FROM dual
CONNECT BY Level <= &1
```